# Where to look for a forum thread in database?

Tags: 6, nodes

In Drupal 6 forum, a user reported that her thread has suddenly disappeared.

I am wondering in which database table should I look for the thread, and what might be the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how 6 version works with forum (because I've never used 6v), but in d7 forum is actually is a node (threads are node types). I thinks you can search for forum table which holds the nids of threads and node and node_type tables for actually for that nodes and thread type...

To find the node by Title:
Open your PhpMyAdmin from browser -> select your db -> open 'node' table -> switch to SQL tab -> SELECT * FROM node WHERE title = "YOUR TITLE"

EDIT:
threads are taxonomies, not node types (based on comment of Mohammad Ali Akbari)

Comment: The only thing that I know of the missed thread is the title. How should I query it?

Comment: Open your PhpMyAdmin from browser -> select your db -> open 'node' table -> switch to SQL tab -> SELECT * FROM `node` WHERE title = "YOUR TITLE"

Comment: As I know threads are taxonomies and topics are nodes.

Comment: @MohammadAliAkbari Sorry, you're right absolutely. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @xurshid29. You were right. I could find the topic using this qurey:  select * from node where title like "%The lost topic title%" ; Please add this to that I can accpet your answer